# Не могу установить библиотеку с названием "simple-draw"

Tags: python, библиотеки

Устанавливал через команду **pip install simple-draw**, pip пытался обновлять, попытался **установить другой пакет** - **вроде установился**, а с этим что тогда не так?
Система х64

Вот, что выдаёт строка, после ввода команды

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install simple-draw
Collecting simple-draw
  Using cached simple_draw-2.7.0.tar.gz (7.5 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pygame==2.0.0
  Using cached pygame-2.0.0.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]


      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\PFVS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mlmiv4d\pygame_ebcc03a000a649d08783bc3026a1588f\setup.py", line 318, in <module>
          buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
        File "C:\Users\PFVS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mlmiv4d\pygame_ebcc03a000a649d08783bc3026a1588f\buildconfig\config.py", line 221, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
        File "C:\Users\PFVS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mlmiv4d\pygame_ebcc03a000a649d08783bc3026a1588f\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 574, in main
          return setup_prebuilt_sdl2(prebuilt_dir)
        File "C:\Users\PFVS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mlmiv4d\pygame_ebcc03a000a649d08783bc3026a1588f\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 499, in setup_prebuilt_sdl2
          DEPS.configure()
        File "C:\Users\PFVS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mlmiv4d\pygame_ebcc03a000a649d08783bc3026a1588f\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 336, in configure
          from . import vstools
        File "C:\Users\PFVS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mlmiv4d\pygame_ebcc03a000a649d08783bc3026a1588f\buildconfig\vstools.py", line 11, in <module>
          compiler.initialize()
        File "D:\Everything For IT\PYTHON\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
          vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
        File "D:\Everything For IT\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 140, in msvc9_query_vcvarsall
          return EnvironmentInfo(arch, ver).return_env()
        File "D:\Everything For IT\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1740, in return_env
          [self.VCIncludes,
        File "D:\Everything For IT\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1282, in VCIncludes
          return [join(self.si.VCInstallDir, 'Include'),
        File "D:\Everything For IT\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 840, in VCInstallDir
          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(msg)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.12-VC.zip 6839b6ec345ef754a6585ab24f04e125e88c3392
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.12-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\jpegsr9d.zip:
      Downloading... https://pygame.org/ftp/prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip 3a5af3427b3aa13a0aaf5c4cb08daaed341613ed
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip:
      copying into .\prebuilt-x64
      Path for SDL: prebuilt-x64\SDL2-2.0.12
      ...Library directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.12/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.12/include
      Path for FONT: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_ttf-2.0.15
      ...Library directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/include
      Path for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_image-2.0.5
      ...Library directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/include
      Path for MIXER: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4
      ...Library directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/include
      Path for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64
      ...Library directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/lib
      ...Include directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/include
      DLL for SDL2: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.12/lib/x64/SDL2.dll
      DLL for SDL2_ttf: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64/SDL2_ttf.dll
      DLL for SDL2_image: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64/SDL2_image.dll
      DLL for SDL2_mixer: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x64/SDL2_mixer.dll
      DLL for portmidi: prebuilt-x64/lib/portmidi.dll
      Path for FREETYPE not found.
      ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
      Path for PNG not found.
      ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
      Path for JPEG not found.
      ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
      DLL for freetype: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64/libfreetype-6.dll

      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Разобравшись в деталях, Pycharm утверждает, что проблема не в нем. Может важно, что сам python и pycharm установлены на диск D, а система на диск С? ОС: windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что все намного проще. Просто библиотека не поддерживала Python версии 3.10. Скачав, версию Python 3.6 и установив, получилось скачать библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

А вы читали текст ошибки? Там сказано, что нужно установить Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 и выше. У вас он установлен? Самое время это сделать

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Потерял эту строку :(

Но в любом случае, я посмотрел - у меня установлена версия microsoft visual c++ redistributable 2015 -2022 (x64\х84) - 14.31.31005 (помимо других версий)